# Classic ASP: How to write unicode string data in classic ASP?

Tags: unicode, asp-classic, utf-8

How can I show an nvarchar column that stores unicode data (Entered with the zawgyi1 font) in a classic ASP web page?

When I retrieve and write the value to the page, it shows "?????". I set my ASP page's content type of UTF-8 with the following meta tag:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Unfortunately, the text is still rendered as "?????".

Any suggestions or ideas on how to display unicode values in a classic ASP page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about your codepage definition at the top of your page?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works for me. I just add that script at my page. Thanks a lot! I can't reply immediately 'coz I can't be online that days. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it fun when you get an up vote on a question you answered 5 years ago.

Answer (score 17):

The Content-Type meta header informs the browser to treat the content sent as a UTF-8 encoded text stream.  It doesn't ensure that the stream sent is actually UTF-8.  To handle UTF-8 correctly you need to do 3 things:-

1. Ensure your static content is saved in a UTF-8 compatible encoding.
2. Ensure your dynamic content is encoded to UTF-8.
3. Inform the client that the content is UTF-8 encoded.

**Item 1** requires either that you actually save the ASP file as a UTF-8 encoded file or that all your static content in the file is within the ASCII character range (0-127).  Note if you save as UTF-8 then all your server-side script must use characters within the ASCII character range. In Visual Studio you can do so by "Saving the file AS..." and then clicking on the little arrow on the Save button.

**Item 2** requires that the `Response.CodePage` property is set to the UTF-8 code page 65001, you can do this in code or by adding the attribute `CODEPAGE=65001` to the `<%@ %>` declarations on the first line of the ASP file.  If you do it in code you must set it before any calls to `Response.Write`.
AND: do not use chr or asc functions (these are buggy when using 65001) but use chrw and ascw instead.

**Item 3** requires that the `Content-Type` header contains the `charset=UTF-8` qualifier.  As you are already doing you can do this with the META header.  Personally I find that to be a bit of kludge, I prefer to use `Response.Charset = "UTF-8"` in code.  This places the qualifier on the true `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Comment: Thanks AnthonyWJones your Item2 work with my problem. Thanks!

Comment: On our site even though we had the meta element added in the html I still had to add the Response.Charset, thanks Anythony.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful script to batch-convert ASP files from ANSI to UTF-8 encoding:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>ASP UTF-8 Converter - TFI 13/02/2015</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY style='font-face:arial;font-size:11px'>
<%
Dim fso, folder, files, NewsFile, sFolder, objFSO, strFileIn, strFileOut
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitefolder"

Function ANSItoUTF8( ANSIFile)
   UFT8FileOut=ANSIFile&".utf8" 
   Set oFS    = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
   Set oFrom  = CreateObject( "ADODB.Stream" )
   sFFSpec    = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName(ANSIFile)
   Set oTo    = CreateObject( "ADODB.Stream" )
   sTFSpec    = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName(UFT8FileOut)
   oFrom.Type    = 2 'adTypeText
   oFrom.Charset = "Windows-1252"
   oFrom.Open
   oFrom.LoadFromFile sFFSpec
   oTo.Type    = 2 'adTypeText
   oTo.Charset = "utf-8"
   oTo.Open
   oTo.WriteText oFrom.ReadText
   oTo.SaveToFile sTFSpec,2
   oFrom.Close
   oTo.Close
   oFS.DeleteFile sFFSpec
   oFS.MoveFile sTFSpec,sFFSpec
End Function

ConvertFiles fso.GetFolder(sFolder), True

Function ConvertFiles(objFolder, bRecursive)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder
    For each objFile in objFolder.Files
        If Ucase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "ASP" Then
            ANSItoUTF8 objFile.path
            response.write "&bull; Converted <B>"&fso.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)&"</B> from ANSI to UTF-8<BR>"
        End If
    Next

    If bRecursive = true then
        For each objSubFolder in objFolder.Subfolders
            ConvertFiles objSubFolder, true
        Next
    End If
End Function

%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```