# SQL use Unicode N in a Stored Procedure with variable

Tags: sql, unicode, asp-classic

I have the following Stored Procedure, Im looking for the correct syntax so I can play the Comments Value in the Comments column with N in front end the value for Unicode I need save Russian Characters Values

So at the moment the comments value is being passed as such

@comments

I want to do

N@comments but not working

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertContactUs]
(
@title VARCHAR(20) = default,
@forename VARCHAR(100) = default,
@surname VARCHAR(100) = default,
@gender VARCHAR(50) = default,
@address1 VARCHAR(100) = default,
@address2 VARCHAR(100) = default,
@city VARCHAR(50) = default,
@county VARCHAR(50) = default,
@country INT = default,
@zipcode VARCHAR(50) = default,
@email VARCHAR(200) = default,
@comments NVARCHAR(MAX) = default,
@mailinglist BIT = default,
@address3 VARCHAR(100) = default,
@dateOfBirth datetime = default
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO tblContactUs (
dateAdded,
title,
forename,
surname,
gender,
address1,
address2,
city,
county,
country,
zipcode,
email,
comments,
mailinglist,
address3,
dateOfBirth)
VALUES (
getdate(),
@title,
@forename,
@surname,
@gender,
@address1,
@address2,
@city,
@county,
@country,
@zipcode,
@email,
@comments,
@mailinglist,
@address3,
@dateOfBirth
)

SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN
```

;

Comment: As an aside, it's a bad idea to name a stored procedure with "sp***"  in SQL Server since the query analyzer ALWAYS searches for a system stored proc if it has that naming convention.

Comment: @JNK It is `sp_` not `sp` that has that behaviour.

Comment: @Martin - I thought it only took SP...but right you are!

Comment: Ok good to know anyway !

Comment: i have updated my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856239/classic-asp-how-to-write-unicode-string-data-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Nvarchar` data type in table's fields and stored procs parameters.

**ADDED**

See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856239/classic-asp-how-to-write-unicode-string-data-in-classic-asp)** link, maybe this will help you.

Comment: Hey Igor, yup as you can see in the stored procedure above I am

i.e @comments NVARCHAR(MAX) = default

But no joy

Comment: What about field in the table?

Comment: Yeah I changed that to NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: So your saying when I use NVARCHAR theres no need for me to look at add N before the value when inserting into DB

Comment: @StevieB - the N just makes whatever follows in the single quotes in unicode format.

Comment: @StevieB How do you call this stored procedure?

Comment: @JNK Yeah I think I need that though in my stored procedures because Im having issues saving russian characters 

i.e if i do plain sql UPDATE    tblContactUs
SET              comments = N'Админ'
WHERE     (id = 2228) it saves fine and im trying to get this same logic in a stored procedure with  a variable but proving impossible

Comment: @igor in classis ASP
Dim comments  : comments  = database_FilterInput(request.Form("comments"))

Set objSP = SQLGetProcedure("spInsertContactUs")
...
SQLSetProcedureParam objSP, "comments", comments
...

Comment: What is `SQLSetProcedureParam`? I can't see many google results for that. Maybe use SQL profiler to see what your asp application is sending to the server.

Comment: AH sorry its a customer method..but when I print out to the screen the value of comments before it goes into the stored procedure the value is Админ. So no issue on the server I think. I just need to find a way to get a N in front of that variable

Comment: @StevieB I have added link to my answer. please, see on it. maybe it is a problem asp, i think. luck

Comment: @StevieB - Just because the screen shot shows Russian characters doesn't mean that's how it's being passed back to the database. My guess is that it's being converted away from unicode somewhere between when it is in the form field and when it gets passed to the server. SQL Profiler should be able to confirm this for you.

Comment: @igor Yup that worked !

<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%> added to top of page + changing column type to NVARCHAR did the trick

Comment: @Tom H. Yup your right, just realised this to.

And also whats SQL Profiler ?

Comment: SQL Profiler is a tool that comes with MS SQL Server. It lets you monitor exactly what is coming into the server. You can filter which events you track so you could see the exact stored procedure call as the server is seeing it. It can be a very useful debugging tool in these situations.

Comment: Tom H. I.e do i need to keep watching it in real time waiting for inserts to be done or how would that work i.e can i run some dummy values in it

Answer (score 0):

This works.  I figured it out myself:

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@prc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strPrc;
```

You need to change your SqlDbType into NVarChar.  You also need to change the field into Nvarchar field and the stored procedure into that too.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @a nvarchar(50)
set @a =N'تست'

exec('INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblP] ([productVal],[name],[month])  VALUES ( 9, '+'N'''+@a+''',1)')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblP] ([productVal],[year],[month])  VALUES ( 9, N'تست',1)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.