# How to convert numeric character reference to Unicode in classic ASP?

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic, ncr

I have a website in Classic ASP. I need to export some data from a database to CSV files.

Some of the data (from the database) is in numeric character reference (NCR). These characters all start with the characters "&#". These are actually Chinese characters represented in NCR (i.e. a number string spelling out the unicode character number). For example: &#39321;&#36771;&#29482;

How do I decode these Chinese characters which are currently in NCR to their actual Chinese characters (maybe in unicode format), in the exported CSV file, so that when I open up this file in Excel or Google Sheets, these Chinese characters will show up properly (display the actual Chinese characters)?

For example &#39321;&#36771;&#29482; should be actually displayed as 香辣猪

In Excel, I can actually use the following to do the conversion:

```
=UNICHAR(39321)&UNICHAR(36771)&UNICHAR(29482)
```

But, I would like to pre-convert those NCR to unicode when exporting to CSV. Is there a way to do this? What is the equivalent of UNICHAR in Classic ASP?

Comment: The following may be of relevance : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856239/classic-asp-how-to-write-unicode-string-data-in-classic-asp and https://www.hanselman.com/blog/internationalization-and-classic-asp

Comment: Thanks, but I need to convert the numbers to actual Chinese characters in unicode (or another encoding), which Excel or Google Sheets can directly display.

Comment: you can use `String.fromCharCode(txt.match(/&#(\d+);/)[1])` to decode

Comment: Please note that I am using classic ASP, which doesn't support such functions.

Comment: @JonP Nope, they just need to decode the HTML encoding and make sure the page response charset is `UTF-8`.

Comment: @JK can classic ASP support substring and split javascript functions ?

Comment: @MikeSteelson Classic ASP is server-side post processing language. It supports active scripting languages like VBScript and JScript (ECMAScript v3).

Answer (score -1):

In google sheet, if you want to upload a csv file whith html special characters, try

```
function importCsvFromIdCodeHtml() {
  var id = '13tlu9eYb5Ty3L45_RKibsfHjOXyUxeX3'; // adapt the id to your own file id
  var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  csvData.forEach((rng, row) => {
    rng.forEach((r, col) => {
      code = (ExtractAllRegex(r, '&#([0-9]+);', 1))
      code.forEach(function (c) { r = r.replace(`&#${c};`, String.fromCharCode(c)) })
      csvData[row][col] = r
    })
  });
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  f.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]);
}
```

```js
  var txt = '&#39321;'
  var char = String.fromCharCode(txt.match(/&#(\d+);/)[1]);
  console.log(char)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with server-side processing in Classic ASP?

Comment: nothing with ASP ...but the demand is not very specific and among all sentences, J K ask `in the exported CSV file, so that when I open up this file in Excel or Google Sheets, these Chinese characters will show up properly` thx to not downvote ... I add also a snippet to show how to transform characters

Comment: i think that it could be interested to keep the format &#xxxxx; in the server and decode when necessary in excel or google sheets !

Comment: HTML character encoding is what people use when they don’t understand how to encode data properly. There is no reason to store unicode data in a HTML encoded string in a modern DB.